# How to make text database for a local website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-database

I am doing a website-like help section for commercial software. For this purpose the website will actually be installed locally along the software and not on server, therefore I cant use server tools for making a database. I am using javascript, jquery and CSS (no SQL or PHP).

In order to make repeating text sections easily modifiable I need some form of text database, that I can modify manually or page-wise via javascript/jquery.

For instance: lets say that the same text description of a specific software property is displayed in 5 different pages and even multiple times across the same page. This kind of descriptions will be later properly modified by the software developer, who will access it from the page (using pop-up text inputs), and that modification must apply over the entire website for that property.

How could I make that kind of thing possible?

Again, keep in mind that this website will be stored locally on disk.

Comment: So when someone updates it how will other people using the site see that change?

Comment: [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) is the start point for you.

Comment: The end product is meant to be distributed locally along the software as a non-modifiable help section. Modifications need to be made only by the software developer alongside of making the software (such as writing descriptions of software properties)

Answer (score 0):

You need a JavaScript Templating Engine. One of the first and good ones is [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/). You can use it to create a layout once and apply the layout for all the data that you have, this way, you separate the data and presentation.

Say this is the base layout of your item:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have multiple items, you can use JSON as the feeds:

```
[
  {
    title: "My Post 1",
    body: "This is my first post!"
  },
  {
    title: "My Old Post",
    body: "This is my first post!"
  },
  {
    title: "My Latest Post",
    body: "This is my first post!"
  },
  {
    title: "My New Post",
    body: "This is my first post!"
  }
]
```

And you can apply the same layout for all the four posts! The above code gets executed in the client side, this way:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My Post 1</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My Old Post</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My Latest Post</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My New Post</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
```

For more information on executing, compiling the template, check out the [docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: Is it possible to permanently modify these items then using javascript/jquery? For instance, can you replace the word "first" to "second" of the second feed using text input from a web page?